# Browser Displays plain text not HTML for XML/XSLT

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I am using XSLT to display an XML file into HTML with IE11.
Instead of HTML all I see is plain text.
Both files are saved to the same folder.

I have compared/based my xsl file off of the example at w3schools

The two files are below.

RuleDefinitions.xml:

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type= "html/xsl" href= "RuleDescriptions.xsl"?>
 <rules>
    <rule>
        <term>FCFPriRegExp</term>
        <title>ClassNameRegexp</title>
        <description>This rule specifies the naming conventions for private final
         class fields.  The definition is done with a regexp (Regular
         expression)</description>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <term>RegExpPrefixForMethodReturingBoolean</term>
        <title>MethodReturningBoolean</title>
        <description>This rule specifies the regexp for a method returning a
         boolean value. In general a method returning a boolen is phrased like a
         question and should normally comply to isEmpty(), hasMoreElements(),
         areBlack(), ... Here you can specify a regexp which describes the name
         for methods returning a boolean value.</description>
    </rule>
```

RuleDefinitions.xsl

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
      xlmns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <html xlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head>
             <title>Java Code Standard Rules</title>
         </head>
         <body>
             <table border="1">
                 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                     <th>Term</th>
                     <th>Title</th>
                     <th>Description</th>
                 </tr>
                 <xsl:for-each select="rules/rule">
                 <tr>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="term"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                     <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                 </tr>
                 </xsl:for-each>
             </table>
         </body>
     </html>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with the samples you show, although in the first case it might just be a typo in your question.

Firstly, in your XML sample, you are missing the closing `</rules>` tag, so your XML is not well-formed.

Secondly, and probably more likely to be the cause, is that you have mis-spelt "xmlns" in the namespace declaration for the "xsl" prefix.

Instead of this...

```
xlmns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

It should be this.

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

EDIT: And as mentioned in comments (Thanks wero!) you should also check your file names are correct. The XML contains a reference to "RuleDescriptions.xsl", but in your question you have labelled the file as "RuleDefinitions.xsl"

Comment: Good spot! I've amended that to my answer too. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you, @TimC and wero,

The file names are typos, but the code is copy-and-paste, although I did not include the entire 1,000+ line XML file, so the "</rules>" was there.

I do appreciate your help.